# How I can grab back from textbox id to PID?

Tags: jquery, html

**This part is jQuery**

```
var PId = ''; //Here I declare the PID
var objA = new A();
objA.AID = AID;
objA.PId = PId;  
$('div[data-id="divDetailPopupControl"] div[data-id="accordion"]').find('div[data-type="txtPropertyId"]').attr('data-type', 'txtPId' + i).html();
$('div[data-id="divDetailPopupControl"] div[data-id="accordion"]').find('div[data-type="txtPId' + i + '"]').attr('PId' + i, item.PId).html();
//Here I console .log to check the result whether work or not. but now still not working.. 
console.log($('div[data-id="divDetailPopupControl"] div[data-id="accordion"]').find('div[data-type="txtPId' + i + '"]'));
```

**This part is HTML**

```
 <div data-id="Detail">
   <div id="ItemDetails" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
     <div class="panel-body">
       <div style="margin: 2px; background-color: white; padding: 10px; max-height: 500px; overflow:auto;">
         <div class="spacer-custom"></div>
         <div data-type="txtPId" display="hidden"></div>
          <div class="form-inline" role="form">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-2 left">
               <label class="control-label body-blue">Title No: </label>
            </div>
                 <div class="col-xs-3">
                   <div data-type="txtTitleNumber"></div>
                 </div>
```

This is the ouptput I display ID inside hidden textbox. https://gyazo.com/0f53616f8f268ccdd74aee76d9a040ff

Hi guys, 
 1. How I can get back the PID from textbox? 
 2. Using item.PID i can get actual result. 
Thank You.

Comment: I can't see where you declared the `i`. Also, `but now still not working` it's not returns the `PID` or it not `find` the input at all?

Comment: `i` is looping sorry not include this

Comment: Can you create a **working** [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)? Also, can you answer my for my second question (the not working part).

Comment: `<div data-type="txtPId" display="hidden"></div>` this is grab the ID already have ID here

Comment: I need to find the PID now. this picture already provided the ID put into textbox `<div data-type="txtPId" display="hidden"></div>`.. Now how I can grab back for PID use again? https://gyazo.com/0f53616f8f268ccdd74aee76d9a040ff

Comment: `$('div[data-id="divDetailPopupControl"] div[data-id="accordion"]').find('div[data-type="txtPId' + i + '"]').attr('prid' + i);`

Comment: console.log `undefined`.. still cannot grab the ID.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118136/discussion-between-mosh-feu-and-kh-lim).

Comment: `var param = { 
'AID': AID, 
'PId': $('div[data-id="divDetailPopupControl"] div[data-id="accordion"]').find('div[data-type="txtPId' + i + '"]').attr('PId' + i),` here I cannot defined.